# Remote Validation using Fluent Validation in Asp.Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

My code is :

```
public class UniqueEmailPropertyValidator : FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider
{

    public UniqueEmailPropertyValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext, PropertyRule rule, IPropertyValidator validator)
         : base(metadata, controllerContext, rule, validator)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        if (!this.ShouldGenerateClientSideRules())
            yield break;

        var formatter = new MessageFormatter().AppendPropertyName(Rule.PropertyName);
        string message = formatter.BuildMessage(Validator.ErrorMessageSource.GetString());

        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "remote",
            ErrorMessage = message
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("url", "/api/validation/uniqueemail");

        yield return rule;
    }
```

Now the error is :

> FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider is not accessible due to its
>   protection level

Comment: Did you checked this? https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/remote-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation/

Comment: yeah dear i have checked that article but it exactally for asp.net mvc  not for core

Comment: This is a result of the changes of the pipeline for .net core, you are probably going to need to make some changes as that base class is `internal` in source

Comment: And based on comments from the developer as to the structure of core mvc, this isn't possible now.

Comment: Then how can it be possible to do remote validation or custom validation in asp.net core mvc?

Comment: ok finally I have do custom validation in asp.net core mvc...If anyone asked about code please comment me I will provide the code

Comment: @MuhammadAsif i would like to see this code

Answer (score 3):

First create your server-side validator

```
using FluentValidation.Validators;
using FluentValidationSample.Services;

namespace FluentValidationSample.ModelsValidations
{
    public class UniqueEmailValidator : PropertyValidator
    {
        private readonly IUsersService _usersService;

        public UniqueEmailValidator(IUsersService usersService)
                : base("It's already in use.")
        {
            _usersService = usersService;
        }

        protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
        {
            return context.PropertyValue != null &&
                    _usersService.IsUniqueEmail((string)context.PropertyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a ClientValidator to produce the required metadata:

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using FluentValidation.Internal;
using FluentValidation.Resources;
using FluentValidation.Validators;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;

namespace FluentValidationSample.ModelsValidations
{
    public class RemoteClientValidator : ClientValidatorBase
    {
        public string RemoteUrl { set; get; }

        public RemoteClientValidator(PropertyRule rule, IPropertyValidator validator) :
            base(rule, validator)
        {
        }

        public override void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-remote", GetErrorMessage(context));
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-remote-url", RemoteUrl);
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            var formatter = ValidatorOptions.MessageFormatterFactory().AppendPropertyName(Rule.GetDisplayName());
            string messageTemplate;
            try
            {
                messageTemplate = Validator.Options.ErrorMessageSource.GetString(null);
            }
            catch (FluentValidationMessageFormatException)
            {
                messageTemplate = ValidatorOptions.LanguageManager.GetStringForValidator<NotEmptyValidator>();
            }
            return formatter.BuildMessage(messageTemplate);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally introduce them to system:

```
namespace FluentValidationSample.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IUsersService, UsersService>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddFluentValidation(
                fv =>
                {
                    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<RegisterModelValidator>();
                    fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;

                    fv.ConfigureClientsideValidation(clientSideValidation =>
                    {
                        // ...

                        clientSideValidation.Add(
                            validatorType: typeof(UniqueEmailValidator),
                            factory: (context, rule, validator) =>
                                        new RemoteClientValidator(rule, validator)
                                        {
                                            RemoteUrl = "/Home/ValidateUniqueEmail"
                                        });
                    });
                }
            );
        }
```