# Razor pages fluent validation server side not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-5.0

I user fluent validation to validate my forms.
I use asp.net core (razor pages).
It work correctly in client side, but when I removed jquery validation scripts to test server side validation I see it doesn't work and ModelState is true.
How can I fix this problem. Is there a any solution?

This is Page Model Properties

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user role name
    /// </summary>
    [HamiResourceDisplayName("Security.Role.Fields.Name")]
    [BindProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user role system name
    /// </summary>
    [HamiResourceDisplayName("Security.Role.Fields.SystemName")]
    [BindProperty]
    [PageRemote(
        //ErrorMessage = "Already exists",
        AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken",
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        PageHandler = "CheckSystemName"
    )]
    public string SystemName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicate whether the user role is for managers
    /// </summary>
    [HamiResourceDisplayName("Security.Role.Fields.ManagerRole")]
    [BindProperty]
    public bool IsManagerRole { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the level of manager if it's a manager role
    /// </summary>
    [HamiResourceDisplayName("Security.Role.Fields.ManagerLevel")]
    [BindProperty]
    public int? ManagerLevel { get; set; }
```

This is OnPost

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();
        var role = new Role()
        {
            Name = Name,
            Inactive = false,
            IsSystemRole = false,
            SystemName = SystemName,
            IsManagerRole = IsManagerRole,
            ManagerLevel = IsManagerRole ? ManagerLevel : null
        };
        await _userService.InsertRoleAsync(role);
        return RedirectToPage("/Security/Roles/Index");
    }
```

And finally this is my validation

```
public class CreateRolesValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateModel>
{
    public CreateRolesValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessageAwait(localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Security.Role.Fields.Name.Required"));
        RuleFor(x => x.SystemName).NotNull().WithMessageAwait(localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Security.Role.Fields.SystemName.Required"));
        //RuleFor(x => x.SystemName).IsUniqueRoleSystemName().WithMessageAwait(localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Security.Role.SystemName.SystemNameAlreadyExists"));
        RuleFor(x => x.ManagerLevel).NotNull().DependentRules(() =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.IsManagerRole).Must(x => x.Equals(true));
        }).WithMessageAwait(localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Security.Role.Fields.ManagerLevel.Required"));
    }
}
```

For example NotEmpty() for "Name" works correctly on client side but not in server side and doesn't catch as an invalid model state.

Comment: I should mentioned that I used .NotEmpty and .NotNull form some rolues and result was same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a separate class to store the model properties, then, add validate for it and use it in the razor page.

For example: Create a RoleViewModel:

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user role name
    /// </summary> 
    [BindProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user role system name
    /// </summary> 
    [BindProperty]
    [PageRemote(
        //ErrorMessage = "Already exists",
        AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken",
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        PageHandler = "CheckSystemName"
    )]
    public string SystemName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicate whether the user role is for managers
    /// </summary> 
    [BindProperty]
    public bool IsManagerRole { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the level of manager if it's a manager role
    /// </summary> 
    [BindProperty]
    public int? ManagerLevel { get; set; }
}
public class CreateRolesValidator : AbstractValidator<RoleViewModel>
{
    public CreateRolesValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.SystemName).NotNull();
        //RuleFor(x => x.SystemName).IsUniqueRoleSystemName().WithMessageAwait(localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Security.Role.SystemName.SystemNameAlreadyExists"));
        RuleFor(x => x.ManagerLevel).NotNull().DependentRules(() =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.IsManagerRole).Must(x => x.Equals(true));
        });
    }
}
```

Then, register the validate service in the ConfigureServices method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages().AddFluentValidation();

        services.AddTransient<IValidator<RoleViewModel>, CreateRolesValidator>();
    }
```

Then in the Create.cshtml.cs file:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public RoleViewModel Role { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();
       
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
}
```

and Create.cshtml: already disabled the client-side validation

```
@page
@model RazorWebApplication.Pages.CreateModel

<form method="post">

    Name: <input asp-for="Role.Name" class="form-control" /> <span asp-validation-for="Role.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    <br />
    SystemName: <input asp-for="Role.SystemName" class="form-control" /> <span asp-validation-for="Role.SystemName" class="text-danger"></span>
    <br />
    IsManagerRole: <input asp-for="Role.IsManagerRole" class="form-control" /> <span asp-validation-for="Role.IsManagerRole" class="text-danger"></span>
    <br />
    ManagerLevel: <input asp-for="Role.ManagerLevel" class="form-control" /> <span asp-validation-for="Role.ManagerLevel" class="text-danger"></span>

    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submtit" />
</form>

@*@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}*@
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Really tanks. It solved my problem. Do you know how to use remote validation when use separate class. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: @HamedNaghdi, Glad to hear the reply helps you solve the problem. For the remote validation, I didn't find the related description in the Fluent validation document, just find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702973/). If not using Fluent Validation, you could add the property (remote validation) in the page model, instead of adding it to the above class (which is using fluent validation), then refer  [this article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/343/improved-remote-validation-in-razor-pages) to achieve the remote validation.